# how to change thickness of two doughnut charts in chartjs

Tags: reactjs, typescript, charts, chart.js

How can I change the thickness of two doughnut charts if one is nested inside the other.
Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/doughnut-chart-percentage-kqoi1?file=/src/App.tsx

I want to look it like this:

[image]

I've tried with the options 'cutout' and 'weight' and it works if I would have only one chart, but I can't change both to the same thickness.
I want to have both doughnuts as thin as in the picture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define `cutout: '90%'` on both datasets.

> `cutout`: The portion of the chart that is cut out of the middle. If string and ending with '%', percentage of the chart radius. number is considered to be pixels.

Please take a look on your amended [**Sandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/doughnut-chart-percentage-forked-y0gux)

> Not sure why but I have to press the refresh button inside the Sandbox in order to have the chart drawn correctly. I guess, Sandbox is somehow remembering your original code after I forked it.

Comment: thanks! ok it's as simple as that. I haven't used the value as a string with percentage. I've used it as a number and that's why it didn't work. (proper reading of the docu would have been helpful). Thank you so much for the help. 
Meanwhile I found a workaround and tried to use a third doughnut with white bg as placeholder inside which worked optically. But of course, then I'll take the proper way as you wrote.